# Sum a column in Excel based on two references in the column and two filter reference columns

Tags: excel, match, vlookup, sumifs

I need to sum the valumes of a column, but I need to identify the column based on two values in the column and I have to filter it by the values in two adjecent columns.

Here is an example:

```
Reference1            Act.   Act.   Act.    ...    Bud.   Bud.   Bud.
Reference2            Jan    Feb    Mar     ...    Jan    Feb    Mar

Reference3 Reference4
CAR        BLUE       1      2      3              4      5      6 
CAR        BLUE       1      2      3              4      5      6    
CAR        RED        1      2      3              4      5      6
```

So, I have to add all the CAR & BLUE & Act. & Jan = 1+1 = 2. And similarly for the other columns.

I would like to achieve something as follows:

```
Reference3 Reference4 Reference1 Reference2 Value     
CAR        BLUE       Act.       Jan        2   
CAR        BLUE       Act.       FEB        4
```

The problem I have is that formula to use in the Value column above. I can not do a SUMIFS as the columns in the original source table change. A VLOOKUP don't work as there is no single column for the lookup_value. I thought about using MATCH to identify the column, but as I have two references(1&2) it doesn't work either.

Any ideas on what formula(s) I could use to achive the above.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making a pivot table from your data (this will not make formulas, though, but will nevertheless give you the desired results).

Here is a simple guide on doing that in Excel 2003 - http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/pivottbls/create.php

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Key in a column:

```
= Reference3 & Reference4 & Reference1 & reference2
```

and after use the Subtotal command (Inside Data).
Every time you modify the data, you need to reuse Subtotal